# There is an unknown developer's iPhone Distribution certificate in my keychain. Where does it come from?

Tags: security, xcode, keychain, certificate

I'm an iOS developer, and today I noticed that in my project's build settings, Xcode suggests a Code Signing Identity that I have never seen before. Turns out there is an iPhone Distribution certificate from another developer in my "login" keychain, on both macs that I'm using.

I immediately checked for anything that might indicate that my systems/accounts have been compromised (Apple ID, GitHub account), but everything looks fine, so I assume that I have somehow added it myself (possibly by installing some software using homebrew?).

Still, I'm a bit worried. I did some research and couldn't find any software project by a developer with this name, so I have no idea where this certificate could come from. Keychain Access doesn't show a "Date Added" or "Date Modified" or anything else that could help finding the source.

I don't like this at all. How can I solve this mystery?

[image: Screenshot of the certificate in Keychain Access]

Comment: Do the details under "Subject Name" match certificates that you've generated?  Does googling the details that you've blacked out reveal anything useful? Are you now, or have you previously been in Russia (Country or Region under Subject Name)?

Comment: I haven't generated certificates that match anything listed under Subject Name. The redacted name I*** B*** is the name of a person. If I google that name, I can find two developers with that name, but their work seems completely unrelated to anything I do/use. I have no relations to and have never been in Russia.

Comment: Would be helpful if you did not redact the certificate - without that information it is impossible for us to say anything. if we can see the certificate ID and the name of the developer, then we could possibly track down which software from for example HomeBrew would be involved.